# PHP 5.6.6 loading but not interpreting in Apache2.4 64 bit Windows

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I have installed Apache 2.4.12 (Win64) VC11 from Apache Lounge. Typing `httpd -M` tells me that php5_module is loaded and shared.

I have PHP 5.6.6 win32 VC11 Thread Safe installed.

The Apache server starts just fine, but when I type in the location of a local phpinfo file, it comes up blank. Adding any generic HTML to the file works just fine, but anything between the PHP tags is ignored.  The Apache log is logging server starts and stops, but not noting any errors. The access log shows a server code 200 or 304 for any access to the phpinfo file.

Does anyone have suggestions on where to look for any addition errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, there is a missing `AddHandler php5-script .php` in the config file.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come back and answer the question.